# Java Compare items in Arraylist with similar items in TreeMap

Tags: java, arraylist, treemap

I have a TreeMap that contains all dates of a given year as keys and value for each key is 46. Now the user supply a start date and end date. I want to check capacity (i.e. value for each date i.e. 46) for start date and end date and range in between in the map. How can this be done?

I can create a an arraylist with range of date, and I thought maybe iterating over both structures(arraylist and treemap) at the same time and comparing items would work. Not sure though. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

A navigable map (such as a tree map) can give you a map with a range of keys through its `subMap(fromKey, toKey)` method.

So this should work for you:

```
TreeMap<Date, Integer> map = ...;
int minCapacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
int maxCapacity = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (Integer capacity : map.subMap(fromDate, toDate).entrySet()) {
    minCapacity = Math.min(minCapacity, capacity);
    maxCapacity = Math.max(maxCapacity, capacity);
}
```

Comment: I am not really clear what mincapacity and maxcapacity are? hence am unable to understand the for each.
Another thing is: once I can check the capacity, then I would like to reflect changes in main map and not the sub...how is that done?

Comment: http://www.java-examples.com/get-sub-map-java-treemap-example
this answered the changes reflections...so yeh just unclear about mincap and maxcap

Comment: I haven't understand the original question, but concerning the example I would use NavigableMap.subMap(), but not SortedMap.subMap(). The NavigableMap method allows to specify whether first/last elements need to be included/excluded.

Comment: aha so navigableMap it is. The question basically is for the dates supplied by user, I need to check the corresponding dates in the TreeMap and range between them to see if I could filfill the reservation of seats in those dates. Hence I would need to access the value i.e. number of seats 46. if I can accomodate, then I will decrement by x requested.